# Why doesn't this youtube instant search script allow fullscreen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to add a youtube instant search to my website and found the following script on this site.  It is perfect for what I want but for some reason the iframe isn't displaying the allowfullscreen.  Can someone help with this.  The script is at the following url jsfiddle.net/K6Wnu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be an issue of an `iframe` within an `iframe`. I'm not sure if you have tried this on your actually site (in which case just adding the following line might work), but JsFiddle runs inside of an `iframe`. To test this in JSFiddle (which I have and it works) You can add:

```
 webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen
```

to your `iframe` like so:

```
$(this).html("<iframe width='400' height='250' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+this.id+"?autoplay=1' frameborder='0' webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>");
```

**AND** to JSFiddle's `iframe`. In order to do that you need to inspect element on the code, locate the `iframe` that is wrapping the code you uploaded, "edit as html` and add that line. Here is a screen shot of it working:

[image]